# nginx reverse nodejs apps with context

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I've recently setup an Ubuntu server (18.04) to host several nodejs apps internally. The applications all reside at subdomains (`v1.example.com`, `v2.example.com`) of my main domain, but on different ports. The applications are served with express (as they also act as an API).

What I want to do is, based on a subdomain, redirect my traffic to a determined NodeJS app (with a context). This is my current nginx config:

```
server {                                                              
        listen 80;                                                    
        listen [::]:80;                                               
                                                                      
        server_name v1.example.com www.v1.example.com;
                                                                      
        location / {                                                  
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/v1;             
                proxy_http_version 1.1;                               
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;               
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                
                proxy_set_header Host $host;                          
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                     
        }                                                             
}

server {                                                              
        listen 80;                                                    
        listen [::]:80;                                               
                                                                      
        server_name v2.example.com www.v2.example.com;
                                                                      
        location / {                                                  
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/v2;             
                proxy_http_version 1.1;                               
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;               
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                
                proxy_set_header Host $host;                          
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                     
        }                                                             
}
```

It works if I use this config:

```
server {                                                              
        listen 80;                                                    
        listen [::]:80;                                               
                                                                      
        server_name v1.example.com www.v1.example.com;
                                                                      
        location /v1 {                                                  
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/v1;             
                proxy_http_version 1.1;                               
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;               
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                
                proxy_set_header Host $host;                          
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                     
        }                                                             
}
```

However, the user needs to access `v1.example.com/v1`.

What exactly I want is to access `v1.example.com` and get served by my node app `http://localhost:3000/v1` without modifying the URL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you change

```
location /v1 {
```

to:

```
location / {
```

But leave:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/v1;
```

As it is.

Depending on what you want other URLs to look like at the back end you may want a regular expression that matches the path in the browser and appends it to the path on the proxied localhost request. There's a question here already about how to do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199599/nginx-location-regex-with-proxypass